# Add filter to a custom controller Dunglas API

Tags: api, symfony, bundle

I'm trying to add a filter to a custom controller in symfony2 Dunglas api bundle.
I would like to filter my entities by some parameters when I try to get the object collection. 
For example I have an entity called "store" that have a attribute "telephone", I would like to filter all stores with this parameter.
The url may be something like :

**.../web/app_dev.php/api/stores?_format=json&telephone='1234567'**

But I can' add the filter to my controller... If I try to init a filter the error that appear is this one :

```
{
  "@context": "/DKCore/web/app_dev.php/api/contexts/Error",
  "@type": "Error",
  "hydra:title": "An error occurred",
  "hydra:description": "Error: Call to a member function getDescription() on a non-object",
  "trace": [
    {
      "function": "getSearch",
      "type": "->",
      "class": "Dunglas\\ApiBundle\\Hydra\\Serializer\\CollectionNormalizer",
      "file": "/var/www/html/DKCore/vendor/dunglas/api-bundle/Hydra/Serializer/CollectionNormalizer.php",
      "line": 127,
      "args": []
    },
    {
      "function": "normalize",
      "type": "->",
      "class": "Dunglas\\ApiBundle\\Hydra\\Serializer\\CollectionNormalizer",
      "file": "/var/www/html/DKCore/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Serializer/Serializer.php",
      "line": 124,
      "args": []
    },
    {
      "function": "normalize",
      "type": "->",
      "class": "Symfony\\Component\\Serializer\\Serializer",
      "file": "/var/www/html/DKCore/vendor/dunglas/api-bundle/Controller/ResourceController.php",
      "line": 89,
      "args": []
    },
    {
      "function": "getSuccessResponse",
      "type": "->",
      "class": "Dunglas\\ApiBundle\\Controller\\ResourceController",
      "file": "/var/www/html/DKCore/src/AppBundle/Controller/StoreController.php",
      "line": 43,
      "args": []
    },
    {
      "function": "getListAction",
      "type": "->",
      "class": "AppBundle\\Controller\\StoreController",
      "file": "/var/www/html/DKCore/app/bootstrap.php.cache",
      "line": 3109,
      "args": []
    },
    {
      "function": "call_user_func_array:{/var/www/html/DKCore/app/bootstrap.php.cache:3109}",
      "file": "/var/www/html/DKCore/app/bootstrap.php.cache",
      "line": 3109,
      "args": []
    },
    {
      "function": "handleRaw",
      "type": "->",
      "class": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\HttpKernel",
      "file": "/var/www/html/DKCore/app/bootstrap.php.cache",
      "line": 3071,
      "args": []
    },
    {
      "function": "handle",
      "type": "->",
      "class": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\HttpKernel",
      "file": "/var/www/html/DKCore/app/bootstrap.php.cache",
      "line": 3222,
      "args": []
    },
    {
      "function": "handle",
      "type": "->",
      "class": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\DependencyInjection\\ContainerAwareHttpKernel",
      "file": "/var/www/html/DKCore/app/bootstrap.php.cache",
      "line": 2444,
      "args": []
    },
    {
      "function": "handle",
      "type": "->",
      "class": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Kernel",
      "file": "/var/www/html/DKCore/web/app_dev.php",
      "line": 29,
      "args": []
    },
    {
      "function": "{main}",
      "file": "/var/www/html/DKCore/web/app_dev.php",
      "line": 0,
      "args": []
    }
  ]
}
```

And this is my custom controller :

```
namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Dunglas\ApiBundle\Controller\ResourceController;
use Dunglas\ApiBundle\Event\DataEvent;
use Dunglas\ApiBundle\Event\Events;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Dunglas\ApiBundle\Api\Resource;

class StoreController extends ResourceController
{

    public function getAction(Request $request, $number)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $store = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Store')->findOneBySiteId($number);
        $groups = ['groups' => ['details']];
        $resource = new Resource('AppBundle\Entity\Store');
        $resource->initNormalizationContext($groups);
        $object = $this->findOrThrowNotFound($resource, $store->getId());
        $this->get('event_dispatcher')->dispatch(Events::RETRIEVE, new DataEvent($resource, $object));
        return $this->getSuccessResponse($resource, $object);
    }

    public function getListAction(Request $request)
    {
        $groups = ['groups' => ['list']];
        $filters=['telephone'=>'948314796'];
        $resource = new Resource('AppBundle\Entity\Store');
        $resource->initFilters($filters);
        $resource->initNormalizationContext($groups);
        $data = $this->getCollectionData($resource, $request);
        if (
            $request->get($this->container->getParameter('api.collection.pagination.page_parameter_name')) &&
            0 === count($data)
        ) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException();
        }
        $this->get('event_dispatcher')->dispatch(Events::RETRIEVE_LIST, new DataEvent($resource, $data));
        return $this->getSuccessResponse($resource, $data, 200, [], ['request_uri' => $request->getRequestUri()]);
    }
}
```

Thank you so much for your help.
Regards

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need a custom controller? I think you can just [use the builtin search filter](https://api-platform.com/doc/1.0/api-bundle/filters#search-filter) to do what you want:

```
# app/config/services.yml

services:
    resource.store.search_filter:
        parent:    "api.doctrine.orm.search_filter"
        arguments: [ { telephone: "exact" } ]

    resource.store:
        parent:    "api.resource"
        arguments: [ "AppBundle\Entity\Store" ]
        calls:
            -      method:    "initFilters"
                   arguments: [ [ "@resource.store.search_filter" ] ]
        tags:      [ { name: "api.resource" } ]
```

Then request `GET /api/stores?telephone=1234567` (without quotes).